# Anki/ Latex: Increase maximum Number of Items in itemize environment

Tags: itemize, anki

I use Anki in my maths studies to revise some proofs, which I usually structure within the itemize environment.
Now I came to the situation that Anki/Latex won't display the items which comes after the 23rd item. So there seems to be a kind of maximum, which is very unfortunate because I like the clean look of the itemize environment. So it would be great to not have such a restriction.

My MWE:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX4
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX8
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX12
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX16
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX22
\item XXX23
\item XXX24
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX
\item XXX32
\end{itemize}
```

My Options for the Latex-card are nothing special. I use "create scalable images with dvisvgm", since else only the lines **after** item 23 will be shown in the card.
My Header is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
```

And my styling is also very basic:

```
.card {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
background-color: white;
}
```

and the corresponding back template

```
{{FrontSide}}

<hr id=answer>

[latex]{{Back}}[/latex]
```

I already tried changing the font size, changing width and height.
It would be great if any of you has a recommendation on what to try next.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE Mandy! Can you maybe post a complete MWE?

Comment: Sure! What else do you need? I thought that what I posted is already everything that is necessary.

Comment: it is true, that you posted all bits that make up a MWE, put one would still have to collect the bits and pieces as well as make some assumptions about your workflow and setup. Maybe read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that to see what makes a good MWE.